# A Homotopy equivalence between two sets($A$ and $S^1$)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have to show the set $A=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2>z^2\}$ is homotopy equivalence to the $S^1=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$. I have to find two continuos maps $f$ and $i$ such that $f\circ i$ is homotopy to the identity map from $S^1$ to $S^1$ and $i\circ f$ is homotopy to the identity map from $A$ to $A$. I have take the maps:
\begin{align*}
f\colon \quad A \quad &\longrightarrow \quad S^1, \\
 \begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y   \\
        z  \\
        \end{bmatrix} &\longmapsto   \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{x}{||•||} \\
        \frac{y}{||•||}  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $||•|| $ denotes the norm of the vector$ \begin{bmatrix}
         x \\
        y \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and
\begin{align*}
i\colon \quad S^1 \ \  &\longrightarrow \ \ \ A,\\
\begin{bmatrix}
         x \\
        y \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto  \begin{bmatrix}
         x \\
        y \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

But these maps aren't good (or not?) How can I find the homotopy?

Comment: Your map $f$ looks fine to me. What are you going to use as $i$?

Comment: OK. Sound good. Now what is $f \circ i$, in coordinates? And while we're at it, what's $i \circ f$?

Comment: $f\ circ i $ is good while I don't know $i \cir f$ is homotopy to the map identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)=({x\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},{y\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},0)$ $i(x,y,0)=(x,y,0)$.

$f(i(x,y,0)=(x,y,0)$, $i(f(x,y,0))=({x\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},{y\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},0)$

$h_t(x,y,z)=t(x,y,z)+(1-t)({x\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},{y\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},0)$

Comment: Why (x,y,1) ? In $S^1$ z=0

Comment: You can define $S^1=\{x,y,1\}, x^2+y^2=1\}$, since you have not precise the plan in which lies the circle.

Comment: Yes but I consider S^1 in the plane where $z=0$ sorry

Comment: @DomenicoVuono In your original formulation you have $S^1$ the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$, so you should get rid of the third coordinate alltogether.